# TCP Client/Server Image Transfer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to send an image using a TCP socket. The client connects to the server without any problems and start to receive the data. The problem is when I try to convert the stream to an image using FromStream() method, I get an OutOfMemory Exception. Can anyone help me out? Really important!! Here is the code;

### client snippet

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
```

```
        client.Connect(ipAddress, 9500);
        NetworkStream nNetStream = client.GetStream();

        while (client.Connected)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Connected...";
            byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int i;
            if (nNetStream.CanRead)
            {
                nNetStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);  

                Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(nNetStream); //exception occurs here
                pictureBox1.Image = returnImage;
            }
            else
            {
                client.Close();
                nNetStream.Close();
            }


        }
        client.Close();
    }
```

### server snippet

```
try
            {
                IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.Resolve("localhost").AddressList[0];
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 9500);
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client to connect...");

                while (true)
                {
                    if (server.Pending())
                    {
                        Bitmap tImage = new Bitmap(Image URL goes here);
                        byte[] bStream = ImageToByte(tImage);

                        while (true)
                        {
                            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                            while (client.Connected)
                            {
                                NetworkStream nStream = client.GetStream();
                                nStream.Write(bStream, 0, bStream.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }


            catch (SocketException e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: " + e1);
            }
        }
        static byte[] ImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image iImage)
        {
            MemoryStream mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Thanks a lot in advanced,

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong, including, possibly the protocol you are using. First, the client:

- If you expect a single image, there is no need for the `while` loop
- Your client first does a `Read` which reads some information from the server into the buffer, and then it calls `Image.FromStream(nNetStream)` which will read incomplete data.
- Whenever you read from a stream, keep in mind that a single `Read` call is not guaranteed to fill your buffer. It can return any number of bytes between 0 and your buffer size. If it returns 0, it means there is no more to read. In your case this also means that your client currently has no way of knowing how much to read from the server. A solution here is to have the server send the length of the image as the first piece of information. Another solution would be to have the server disconnect the client after it has sent the information. This may be acceptable in your case, but it will not work if you need persistent connections (e.g. pooled connections on client side).

The client should look something like this (assuming the server will disconnect it after it sends the data):

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(ipAddress, 9500);
    lblStatus.Text = "Connected...";

    NetworkStream nNetStream = client.GetStream();
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(nNetStream);
    pictureBox1.Image = returnImage;
}
```

Next, the server:

- Instead of `Pending`, you can simply accept the client
- The server sends the stream over and over again to the same client, until they disconnect. Instead, send it only once.

The server loop should look something like this:

```
Bitmap tImage = new Bitmap(Image URL goes here);
byte[] bStream = ImageToByte(tImage);

while (true)
{
    // The 'using' here will call Dispose on the client after data is sent.
    // This will disconnect the client
    using (TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        NetworkStream nStream = client.GetStream();

        try
        {
            nStream.Write(bStream, 0, bStream.Length);
        }
        catch (SocketException e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: " + e1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code, Bojan Resnik! Thanks to your good explanation I managed to find the bug in my code as well. However, I would love to see an example on how to do the same but with a persistent connection. I understand the problem that you'll have to inform the client of how many bytes are going to be sent, but anyone who could help us understand by extending Bojan's code?

Answer (score 1):

This part looks funky to me:

```
  byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize]; 
  int i; 
  if (nNetStream.CanRead) 
  { 
    nNetStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);   

    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(nNetStream); //exception occurs here
```

First you read client.ReceiveBufferSize bytes into the "bytes" array, and then you proceed to construct the image from what's left on the stream. What about the bytes you just read into "bytes"?

Comment: it would work for him without `nNetStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use this code(I've created it by myself and tested it and it works perfect.):

```
public void Bitmap ConvertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] receivedBytes)
{
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(receivedBytes);
   return new Bitmap(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); // I recomend you to use png format   
}
```

Use this to convert received byteArray to an image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server is sending the image over and over again:

```
while (client.Connected)
{
    NetworkStream nStream = client.GetStream();
    nStream.Write(bStream, 0, bStream.Length);
}
```

If the server can send data fast enough, the client will probably keep receiving it.

Comment: By only sending the image data once, instead of inside a while loop. Change the "while" into an "if", for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution :

Server side :

```
tImage.Save(new NetworkStream(client), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Cliend side:

```
byte[] b = new byte[data.ReceiveBufferSize];
client.Receive(b);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
Image receivedImag = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

or :

```
Image receivedImag = Image.FromStream(new NetworkStream(client));
```