# How to make real-time image transfer with server-client on the internet

Tags: c#, client-server

I am new in the programming and I have a little knowledge C#. I want to real-time image transfer with C# server-client application on the internet. how do I make it, I need your advise.  very thanks for your help

Comment: you need to give much more information... what exactly is the goal ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I hope these will help you with real time image transfer with c#: using [tcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789294/tcp-client-server-image-transfer) http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7695

Answer (score 0):

depend on your application based-on platform, your answer change.

1- If your are programming a windows based-on application that want to retrieve images from a data source:

It is simple.use a timer control with interval 10ms.and then on  it`s tick event check fro new images on the remote data source.(please more about your data source.is it a sql server database that you store your images on it as a column in  a table, or in a directory on a host that you wan to download images from it)

2- If you are programming a website that want to have a page to do that for you :
you must set a javascript timer and change a src of a img element and show to your contacts(remember,you can do that with ajax ot you can postback your page too)

but for helpful advise i need more details.

Comment: hi very thanks for your answer. my goal develop project mobile_robot with 3G controller for finised work of my university. my project that contain rc truck, mini itx ,webcam,robot arm platform and 3G usb dongle components. I am going to develop project using that components. I will programming C# interface  therefore I need C# server-client application and real-time image transfer on the internet